# cannot enable module after DB migration, only in one environment

Tags: 7, database, migrations

I have 3 environments: `live`, `stage` & `dev`.

I've taken a database backup from `live` and imported into `stage` & `dev`.

I clear all caches on `stage` & `dev` and navigate to `/admin/modules` to turn on `module_a` but on `stage` it's disabled and i'm unable to enable it.

It seems strange that I am enable it locally but it's `disabled` on `stage`.

How do I go about debugging this?

Comment: Is the code base same? I suspect there is missing module which cause the dependent modules disabled.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that is my suspicion, I'm waiting for server team to get back to me with a `git log` I can compare to my local environment. #painful

Comment: Please also to ask for the `git status` :P

Comment: Git logs identical 200 commits back and git status clean minus irrelevant server junk. So I can only assume the codebase is the same.

Comment: Screw git, seeing is believing, just FTP into the `/sites/all/modules` folder and see if there are any folders missing.

Answer (score 0):

The system module builds this form in the function [`system_modules()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.admin.inc/function/system_modules/7.x). It disables a module in the UI under 3 conditions:

- The module is required by your Drupal distribution.
- The module is missing a dependency.
- The module (or one of its dependencies) has version incompatibility with Drupal core.

In any of these cases, you can click the Description fieldset which shows the dependencies required and highlights the ones that are missing.

Another direct method is to utilize the Drush command:

```
drush en module_a
```

Drush will attempt to enable the module and alert you if `module_a` doesn't exist or it has unmet dependencies (which should help you track down what is missing).